# Kohsuke Github API throws "tree.path contains a malformed path component" error on push to a branch

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

I tried to push my files through Kohsuke Github API. While doing so, I am getting this error. I couldn't find any proper explanation or documentation for this. Any lead will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Caused by: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: {"message":"tree.path contains a malformed path component","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/git#create-a-tree"}
at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubConnectorResponseErrorHandler$1.onError(GitHubConnectorResponseErrorHandler.java:62)
at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.detectKnownErrors(GitHubClient.java:473)
at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.sendRequest(GitHubClient.java:435)
at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubClient.sendRequest(GitHubClient.java:403)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.fetch(Requester.java:85)
at org.kohsuke.github.GHTreeBuilder.create(GHTreeBuilder.java:178)
....

Tried to push some files to a branch in a repository.